# Converting excel formula to PHP script

Tags: php, excel

I am new to programming.  I have an excel formula which I want to be converted into PHP
can someone please help me.

Please find the formula below:

```
=(IF(MAX(C4,D4)-MIN(C4,D4)<0.05*MAX(C4,D4)*AND(E4<=0.75*MAX(D4,C4)),"hourglass",1))
```

Comment: It's not that simple. First you will need a data structure (like an array), representing the excel table. Only then you can manage to write this formula in a function or method...

Comment: If you're new to programming, learn and become better. Don't just ask someone to give the solution to you

Answer (score 6):

- `=IF(expr, valueIfTrue, valueIfFalse)` can be converted to `$result = expr ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse`
- Column references can be converted to variable references
- Rest stays pretty much the same mainly due to PHP having case-insensitive keywords and functions

```
$C4 = 1;
$D4 = 2;
$E4 = 3;

$result = ((MAX($C4, $D4) - MIN($C4, $D4) < 0.05 * MAX($C4, $D4)) AND 
          ($E4 <= 0.75 * MAX($C4, $D4))) ? "hourglass" : 1;
```

Comment: +1 for the fact that you offered your time to answer this ungratefully worded question

Comment: @BenCarey yeah I have now edited the PHP code to be even more closer to excel

Comment: I wonder whether the user will even thank you for your time! :-(. Nicely done anyway!

Comment: Even with the question being really incomplete and overly broad your answer did actually help me to solve a problem with excel and PHP. It lead me to think easier about a conversion and less abstract because.